# Different set of fields for each object

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm looking for a way to have a Model, In which each object contains different sets of fields for another Model.

The task is to create an `IntegrationType`. Each object of this model should contain sets of fields needed to create an `Integration` object.
For example, we have a Facebook integration type which should define fields like `app_id`, `key` etc. And then we would have an ability to create `Integration` with Facebook integration type which should store values for these preconfigured fields.

I'm using MySQL database

Comment: You can not have dynamic field in DB, If you want to store different data for each case you can store the data in JSON format.

Comment: MariaDB a fork off MySQL supports dynamic columns https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go for the postgresql `Hstore` field, its a json-like field but a bit more efficient, besides limited than a normal json.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.HStoreField

Comment: I can't accept this answer because I'm using mysql with legacy database

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't saw that. Hmm in that case i would recommend you to use a Json field then